# Problema de retorno en Enumerable en WebApi

Tags: c#, json

Estoy haciendo una webApi, la cual tiene sus entidades y su clase contexto que cree a través de la base de datos, con su respectivo comando.

Todo me esta funcionando perfecto, el drama es cuando quiero retornar un conjunto de objetos en JSON y solo me devuelve uno.

Tengo una clase contexto, que hace las inyecciones de dependencia para todas las entidades.

Si en mi [HttpGet] hago esto:

```
public IEnumerable<Sucursales> Get()
    {
        using (var _context = new hn_asis_testContext())
        {
           return _context.Sucursales.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Me devuelve esto :

```
[
  {
    "sucursalId": 2,
    "nombre": "Santa Clara",
    "barrioId": 1,
    "empleados": [

    ],
    "ventas": [

    ],
    "barrio": null
  },
  {
    "sucursalId": 3,
    "nombre": "Santa Clara",
    "barrioId": 1,
    "empleados": [

    ],
    "ventas": [

    ],
    "barrio": null
  },
  {
    "sucursalId": 4,
    "nombre": "Santa Clara",
    "barrioId": 1,
    "empleados": [

    ],
    "ventas": [

    ],
    "barrio": null
  },
  {
    "sucursalId": 5,
    "nombre": "Santa Clara",
    "barrioId": 2,
    "empleados": [

    ],
    "ventas": [

    ],
    "barrio": null
  }
]
```

Lo que yo quiero lograr, es que en cada Sucursal, con el ID de barrio que le doy devuelva su objeto Barrio, donde no dice Barrio=null.

Entonces implementé esto :

```
public IEnumerable<Sucursales> Get()
    {
        using (var _context = new hn_asis_testContext())
        {

              var lista = new List<Sucursales>();
              var lista2 = new List<Barrios>();
              lista = _context.Sucursales.ToList();
              lista2 = _context.Barrios.ToList();
              foreach (var item in lista)
              {  
                     item.Barrio = lista2.FirstOrDefault(t => t.BarrioId == item.BarrioId);

              }
              return lista.ToList();

        }

    }
```

Lo cual, no devuelve me conjunto de Json, sino UNO solo con el objetivo que quería llegar.

Asi :

```
[
  {
    "sucursalId": 2,
    "nombre": "Santa Clara",
    "barrioId": 1,
    "empleados": [

    ],
    "ventas": [

    ],
    "barrio": {
      "barrioId": 1,
      "nombre": "Santa Clara",
      "clientes": [

      ],
      "empleados": [

      ],
      "sucursales": [

      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Dale una miradita a esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024972/3590533, quizas te ayude. Suerte!

Comment: Cuando tengas código json para publicar, te recomiendo utilizar: http://jsonprettyprint.com/ así es más sencillo pasar la vista :D Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias  @Einer, me ayudaste a solucionarlo ! Y gracias por el consejo Fredy .

Comment: ¡Me alegra que te haya ayudado! Lo voy a poner como respuesta para que otros puedan verla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dale una miradita a esta respuesta en stackoverflow: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024972/3590533, quizas te ayude.

Codigo que soluciona el problema:

```
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => { 
      options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema de tu consulta se debe al procesamiento que estás realizando. Imaginemos que tienes 100,000 sucursales, entonces tendrías que hacer 100,000 subconsultas para obtener los barrios asociados a cada sucursal.

La solución radica en hacer un `JOIN` entre las tablas `Sucursales` y `Barrios`:

```
public IEnumerable<Sucursales> Get()
{
    using (var _context = new hn_asis_testContext())
    {
        var lista = (from p in _context.Sucursales
                     join o in _context.Barrios on p.BarrioId equals o.BarrioId
                     select new {
                            sucursalId = p.sucursalId,
                            nombre = p.nombre,
                            barrioId = p.barrioId,
                            empleados = p.empleados,
                            ventas = p.ventas,
                            barrio = o.nombre
                     }).ToList();

        return lista;
}
```

Comment: Gracias ! La verdad demoraba mucho en responder la solicitud !